# Can not called my CreateController while edit an order from backend

Tags: admin-controller, admin-order-create

I want to change in SaveAction() of  Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController. So for this I have make changes in config.xml like below :

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Mycompany_Modulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                        Mycompany_Modulename_Adminhtml
                    </Mycompany_Modulename>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

and add file at

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales/Order/CreateController.php';

class Mycompany_Modulename_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
{  
}
```

It is working and called SaveAction() when admin create an order.But if admin edit an order that time SaveAction() is called from core file Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extend EditController.php from Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_EditController and put SaveAction into that.